How to merge all PDF files in a folder into one?
According to the documentation, this is done via:
cpdf -merge -idir files -o out.pdf 

This yields an error:
Merge: Must specify one output and at least one input

I don't know how to fix this.

I haven't yet determined how to fix this, but a search found the location of the error message text in the source code in cpdfcommand.ml

Replacing files with actual directory worked, e.g.:
cpdf -merge -idir . -o out.pdf

The web version of the docs doesn't highlight the word files in the following explanation:

Merge all files from directory files, producing out.pdf.

Hence I didn't understand that part. Only after I opened the PDF version, I understood why files didn't work:


Is this an answer? Doesn't sound like one. If it is and the mistake was not replacing files with actual directory with files, that should be made clear.

yes it is. Is it better?
